# How to replace a toast with a textview?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, textview

I'm working on a GSM App. The incoming message from the server is showing as a Toast. How to replace the toast in the following code to a textview?

```
public class GcmMessageHandler extends IntentService {

     String mes;
     private Handler handler;
    public GcmMessageHandler() {
        super("GcmMessageHandler");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
        handler = new Handler();

    }
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
        // in your BroadcastReceiver.
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

       mes = extras.getString("title");
       showToast();
       Log.i("GCM", "Received : (" +messageType+")  "+extras.getString("title"));

        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);

    }

    public void showToast(){
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),mes , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
         });

    }
}
```

Comment: what does your layout look like?

Comment: you can show message as a Notification

Comment: this toast massage are where showing.. what is exactly you want..   i think this is work     textview.settext(mes );

Comment: you can't add text view in intent services

Comment: You can refer to this [example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/widget/textview/android-textview-example/) on how to make a textView. Firstly, you will need to make a layout xml then you need to create the textView in the `onCreate` method then use `setText` method to put the text that you want to display.

Answer (score 3):

You can set TextView as Toasts view like this :

```
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, toast.getXOffset() / 2, toast.getYOffset() / 2);

    TextView textView = new TextView(context);
    textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    textView.setTextSize(30);
    Typeface typeface = Typeface.create("serif", Typeface.BOLD);
    textView.setTypeface(typeface);
    textView.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
    textView.setText(message);

    toast.setView(textView);
    toast.show();
```